# Returning multiple object types from ArrayLists

Tags: java

Basically I have a class "A" that other classes, say "B", "C", and "D" extend. Objects of these types will have string names that are not necessarily unique.

```
public class A {
    //some code
}


public class B extends A {
    // some code
}
```

So classes C & D also extend A, same as B.

Next I have a holder class that has an arraylist to hold the B, C & D objects, (no A objects will go in here).

```
public class Holder {
    List<A> container;

    public Holder() {
        container = new ArrayList<A>();
    }

    public A getItemByName(String s) {
        //return the first object with s == name, or return null
    }

    public A getItemByType(Class c) {
        //return  the first object that matches the class or return null
    }
}
```

These functions can successfully pick out the desired objects but I need to return the objects as B, C & D types. Is there a way of doing this and if so, how?

Comment: If you have a collection that is meant to hold objects of different (and unrelated) types, then an elegant solution may be to implement your container as a Typesafe Heterogenous Container (Effective Java. Item #29. J. Bloch, 2nd Ed.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
public <T extends A> T getItemByType(Class<T> c) {
   for(Object o : container){
      if(c.isInstance(o)){
         return c.cast(o);        
      }
   }
   return null;
}
```

Then you will be able to do

```
B found = holder.getItemByType(B.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following methods can be used to filter out the objects based on `getName()` or the provided type (`Class`).

```
public A getItemByName(String s) {
    return container.stream()
            .filter(obj -> s.equals(obj.getName()))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);
}

public <T extends A> T getItemByType(Class<T> c) {
    return container.stream()
            .filter(c::isInstance)
            .map(c::cast)
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);
}
```

This uses the Java 8 streams together with the `Optional`-class. I would strongly suggest to **not** return null values from your methods, instead the `Optional` class can be used to avoid null checked error-prone code.

Comment: You can probably replace filter lambda by method reference `c::isInstanceof` And you could get rid of your if-then-else if you do a `return stream...findFirst().orElse(null)`.

Comment: Thx @EdwinDalorzo - it's updated (`c::isInstance` and `orElse`)

Comment: Now it looks awesome. Much simpler now and even much easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

They won't be typed as B, C or D objects, because the collection is typed as an A Array.  If that weren't the case, you would either have a magical typechecker, as it would have to know at compile time what was going to happen at run time, or you'd have a contradiction.  Just cast the objects afterwords, or create an overridden function that does what it should on B, C and D objects.

Consider this code:

```
A [] aarray = {B1, C1, D1, B2, B3 };
if(theMoonIsFull) { aarray[3+one()] = C2; } // if the moon is full 
B hopeitsaB = aarray[4];  // this line doesn't compile
```